# how to configure proxy in vite that works the same way as proxy in create-react-app?

Tags: proxy, create-react-app, vite

In `create-react-app` I can add a property to `package.json`:

`"proxy": "https://some.server.com"`

And every time I execute a `fetch` request, every call regardless of path is proxied to the specified target.

In vite, best I could do is something like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://some.server.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    }
  }
})
```

It works, except I need to explicitly specify paths. For example, if I need to proxy fetch requests that do not start with `/api`, I need to rewrite it to `^/(api|something-else)': {...}`

How can I make it work the same way as in `create-react-app`, so I don't have to explicitly specify proxy paths, and so only fetch requests are proxied?